# Default options for launching meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm using `Meteor.Settings` to access secrets stored within a `settings.json`.

Everything works fine using `meteor --settings settings.json`, but ideally i'd like to just call `meteor` and have it automatically pick up the settings. Is there a meteor way of specifying default options to the meteor cli? E.g. a file like `meteor.opts` that would contain flags?

Answer (score 0):

That is what the --settings command is for. I can't see the issue with just running with the --settings command

Comment: On one hand, it's not that bad, on the other, it requires every user of the application to remember  and type the flag with the file location. I am very lazy and forgetful (even with a readme). I prefer the elegance and simplicity of meteor :)